# MVC broken image path

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, image, src

I am using jQuery DatePicker plugin in my MVC application. To display a certain image for Calendar pop-up I am using the following lines

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "../images/Calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "show calendar"
});
```

In my Views I always define my form as follows:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "insertForm", onsubmit = "return confirm('Do you confirm insert operation?')" }))
```

when I run a certain page without any parameters, such as

```
http://localhost:52849/MyController/Insert
```

everything is OK and image of the calendar is shown properly. Also when I inspect the element with Firebug I see the following declaration:

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../images/Calendar.png" alt="Show Calendar" title="Show Calendar"/>
```

and if I copy the Image URL in Chrome I get

```
http://localhost:52849/images/Calendar.png
```

But when I call the page with a parameter as

```
http://localhost:52849/MyController/Insert/6
```

The image dissappears. when I inspect the button with firebug I still see the same declaration as

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../images/Calendar.png" alt="Show Calendar" title="Show Calendar"/>
```

but when I get the Image Url with Chrome I get

```
http://localhost:52849/MyController/images/Calendar.png
```

what is the reason behind it and how can I possibly solve this problem without passing the parameter(s) with query strings or Session variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you're using a relative path for the buttonImage property.

Instead, use an absolute path and the problem will be solved.

eg:

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/myapplication/images/Calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "show calendar"
});
```

(In practice, I usually have a javascript variable defined which contains the application root  and then combine that with the path to a resource: that way if the application has to be deployed to a different path, all the images don't break.)

eg:

```
 var appRoot = '<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>';
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: appRoot + "/images/Calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "show calendar"
});
```

Comment: Replacing 

var appRoot = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;

solved my problem. thank you very much for your help.